# vue.config.js [transpileDependencies] is not work

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, vue-cli

I created a vue(2.x) project with vue-cli.

And I use the `@splidejs/vue-splide` npm module in this project.

This project must support up to IE10...

The `@splidejs/vue-splide` module did not work in IE, so I created a `vue.config.js` file and wrote it as below.

```js
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    "@splidejs/vue-splide"
  ]
}
```

Afterwards I ran the `npm run serve` command again.
But the i.e. error was still not resolved.

Please help me what to do.

There are so many things to do. Get me out of hell's Internet Explorer support.

Comment: You should probably include the module's [dependencies](https://github.com/Splidejs/vue-splide/blob/master/package.json#L26) since it's really only a Vue-wrapper on `@splidejs/splide`

Comment: How can I  include the module's dependencies?

Comment: Oh, as in add `@splidejs/splide` and possibly `@splidejs/splide-extension-video` to your `transpileDependencies` array

Comment: I added them all as per your opinion, but it didn't work.
However, it works when only `@splidejs` is added.
Got a hint in your comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: Using vuejs with CKEditor 5 I got same Issue, so I added the part of `[/ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]src[/\\].+\.js$/]` but I already had the same prop inside so a added in this way: `transpileDependencies: ["vue-echarts", "resize-detector", /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]src[/\\].+.js$/],`. NOTE: Avoid to use **quotation marks**

Answer (score 6):

I wasted a day with this problem.
I write the answer to make sure no developer experiences the same pain as mine.

After creating the `vue.config.js` file, write it as follows.

```js
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    "@splidejs"
  ]
}
```

Even entering both `@splidejs/splide` and `@splidejs/splide-extension-video` does not work in IE.

However, if only `@splidejs` is entered, it works normally in IE.

I don't know the exact reason.
If you know why, please leave a comment.